# Stuck trying to sort parallel arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to sort 2 parallel arrays one with a `String` and one with `int`s in it

I want to sort it by the `int`s and then sort the `String` to match I am using this code:

```
        for (int t = 0; t < calctemp.length - 1; t++) {
            for (i = 0; i < calctemp.length - 1; i++) {
                if (calctemp[i].compareTo(calctemp[i + 1]) > 0) {
                    tmpStr = stringtemp[i];
                    tmpInt = calctemp[i];
                    stringtemp[i] = stringtemp[i + 1];
                    calctemp[i] = calctemp[i + 1];
                    stringtemp[i + 1] = tmpStr;
                    calctemp[i + 1] = tmpInt;
                }
            }
```

This has worked for me before when sorting and string and double array but now I am getting `int cannot be dereferenced` error on the line `if (calctemp[i].compareTo(calctemp[i + 1]) > 0)` 
I am guessing this is due to `int` being a primitive but I cannot figure out what to replace it with to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But why not use a class and implement comparator? -- calctemp creation line?

Comment: where do you declare `i` to be an `int`?

Comment: The i is declared already in the method at the beginning of it as it is used throughout

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes at `calctemp[i].compareTo(calctemp[i + 1])` while `calctemp[i]` is just an int and doesn't have the method `compareTo`.

A quick fix would be to compare as primitives using `>` as follows:

```
if (calctemp[i] > calctemp[i + 1])
```

But in the long run, i would also do it as @MarcoAcierno suggested. Introduce a class which would contain both `int` and `String` representations of the respective values. Then implement a comparator, which would compare the `int` versions as:

```
public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
  return o1.getIntValue() > o2.getIntValue();
}
```

Don't forget to implement implement Comparable interface in your class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer hasanovh sadly this does not work it just says bad operand first type boolean second type int.

Comment: @Chris, that would mean that first part of `<` operator is `boolean` and second is `int`. So, how can the same array have two different types, as here is what i wrote `if(calctemp[i] > calctemp[i + 1])`. ?